# "inflating" xib programmatically in swift using Auto-Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I've asked a simular question before with no working result yet, but it might have too much "stuff" which is irrelevant to the exact issue I'm experiancing:

I used to be an Android-only developer in my current position and did not do any iOS apps before this so I might be troubling myself with the wrong stuff.

I want to load an view from xib which has a parent class I'd love to be able to do something like this (e.g. in UIViewController):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let view = MyView()
    view.unlimitedLabel.text = "bla bla unlimited character string"
    self.view.addSubView(view)
}
```

The MyView would be like this (I'm omitting what I added just to keep it clean):

```
import UIKit

class MyView : UIView {
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var deadlineLabel: UILabel!
}
```

So what init's are recommended, what should I apply to the view to make it respect the autoLayout? I understand it will be hard to do the AutoLayout when the view doesn't know it's parent and such.

for now I'm usually overriding all init's and call a private func like

```
private func setup() {
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: self, options: nil)
    view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    addSubview(view)

}
```

This barely ever works as expected, I have it working for height sometimes, but then the width is not being respected it just takes the xib's width. In general the view will have the xib's in UIBuilder size.

The xib is set correctly it's working fine for tableViewCell's right now. And the "MyView" class is set to the xib's file owner, outlets linked.

Note: I'm on iOS7 using Swift

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I don't remember to be honest. however I assume this is probably not relevant as you won't have to support iOS7 I hope.

I believe if you focus iOS9 and up things just work way better. I didn't have to bother too much with the classes lat time I worked with it.

However now I unfortunately never work with iOS apps anymore.